# Where are FoneMonkey saved scripts stored?

Tags: ios, ui-automation

I'm using FoneMonkey to test my app.

When I save a script, I can see it's directory in the log, but it is wrong: There is no such path as `.../Users/Name/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/5B286FB6-D58E-4D43-947D-3B63591289BB/Documents`

I can't even find iPhone Simulator folder on my Mac... How is that? Where can I find my scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Library folder in user directory is hidden. unhide it or user the terminal to get there.